# How to make letter spacing css rule add space around character?

Tags: css, letter-spacing

In css `letter-spacing` rule, the rule adds space after the character. Now I want to make the space to surround the character instead. Importantly, when I highlight the whole text, the space before first character should be highlighted.

Workarounds that I know:

Use margin-left and margin-right to adjust:

It works, but highlighting text is broken (still does not highlight the space before the first character)

Use left and right to position the text: 
Same issue

Comment: please add your exisiting code it will be easier to help

Comment: Will try to put some sample code after I get back home, but the existing code can be just some text embedded by a span (or div?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margin-left and margin-right you should use

```
.TEXTCLASS {
 padding-left: SOMEVALUE ..... 2px;
 padding-right: SOMEVALUE ..... 2px;
{
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a working example? The OP wants highlighting to work too (i.e. what you get by selecting the text).

Comment: Yes I think the highlight is still broken even if I change margin to padding.

Answer (score 0):

On idea is to add a hidden character at the start to create the space you want.

I will be using the [*zero width space*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character

```css
span {
  background:pink;
  font-size:25px;
  letter-spacing:20px;
}
span:before {
  content:"\80";
}
```

```html
<span>Some text here</span>
```

If you want to be able to select it you need to add it in the code:

```css
span {
  background:pink;
  font-size:25px;
  letter-spacing:20px;
}
```

```html
<span>​ Some text here</span>
```